# Как открыть любое приложение или файл с пк по нажатии на кнопку c#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно открыть рабочую книгу Excel через c#. Никакой работы с данными, просто открыть в дополнительном окне Windows.

Comment: Открыть через программу, которая сопоставлена с расширение файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\temp\\книга.xlsx");
```